# How is the number of memebers in a truss calculated?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures

In a fully connected truss (each node connected to all other nodes), the number of members (bars) is equal to $n(n−1)/2$ where $n$ is the number of nodes.

I don't understand the derivation of this formula. Can you please explain it to me?

reference of the [formula](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0965997821000612#bib0001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are n nodes. Each connects to all the others, so n-1 connections to each node. But if node A is connected to node B then member AB is the same as BA so you've counted each member twice. Hence /2.

So, (n nodes) x (n-1 connections to each node)/(2 because you have doubled up)

Comment: Can you verify the formula for a square truss (with 4 nodes/4 connections) that contains a diagonal member inside? #member = ? vs 5 actual.

Comment: That's not a fully connected truss by this (rather strange) definition. thye formula would say 6 but you've removed one member.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!